# Reload page when AJAX upload completes

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrapping

I am doing multiple file upload in BootStrap it got successfully upload individual file ,but after the total file upload the page is not get refresh.

And below i have attached the code that i have been used in project

```
$('.file-input').fileinput({
        uploadUrl: "http://localhost:61586/Sys/FormFile.ashx?fid=Sample", // server upload action
        browseLabel: 'Browse',
        browseIcon: '<i class="icon-file-plus"></i>',
        uploadIcon: '<i class="icon-file-upload2"></i>',
        removeIcon: '<i class="icon-cross3"></i>',
        layoutTemplates: {
            icon: '<i class="icon-file-check"></i>'
        },
        initialCaption: "No file selected"
    });
```

1.I need all file upload to server and all process completed mean that time i can refresh page

Comment: You need to hook to an event the plugin raises after uploading the files and use `window.location.reload()`. Check the docs to find the most applicable event. I'd suggest [`fileuploaded`](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#event-fileuploaded)

Comment: What kind of refresh you need - only your upload data summary control or full page? If full page - please see answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below, after file is uploaded it gets fired

```
$('.file-input').on('fileuploaded', function(event, data, previewId, index) {
      window.location.reload();
});
```

Here is Link for your reference, it may help you to do

http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#events

Answer (score 0):

Just put `window.location.reload();` at the end of your function in JavaScript

Comment: I would presume the upload is asynchronous, so this isn't going to work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```js
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  window.location.reload();
});
```

or

```
window.location.reload();
```